# Коды стран alpha2 и ISO в Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony4

Нужно сопоставление двухбуквенного кода страны и цифрового, нашел класс `Symfony\Component\Intl\Countries` но там только двухбуквенный, есть ли в symfony 4 такое? Пример Россия: 'RU' и 643

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такая библиотека [moneyphp](https://github.com/moneyphp/money) так вот: в этой библиотеке присутствует [файл](https://github.com/moneyphp/money/blob/master/resources/currency.php) с кодами стран и ISO в виде массива, вы можете либо попробовать эту библиотеку под свои нужны, либо воспользоваться уже готовым массивом с собранными данными. Вы также можете перебрать массив под себя как вам будет надо.

Конкретно для symfony есть эта же библиотке, но в виде [бандла](https://github.com/moneyphp/MoneyBundle).